# google cloud composer library installation failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

while attempting to update the installed pypi packages on my composer env, I'm getting the following error -

```
 UPDATE operation on this environment failed 7 minutes ago with the following error message:
Failed to install pypi packages.
Your service account is missing the required permissions to check the build log for errors. You can access them through Cloud Logging, or by running gcloud builds log fe358f33-51ec-4064-9a75-38af2974976f --project ene-playground.
```

when reading the build logs, it looks like there's a dependency issue which is clearly isn't permission issue -

> google-cloud-vision 1.0.0 has requirement
> google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-videointelligence 1.16.1 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-translate 1.7.0 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-texttospeech 1.0.1 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-speech 1.3.2 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-spanner 1.19.1 has requirement google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have
> google-api-core 2.7.1. google-cloud-secret-manager 1.0.0 has
> requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have
> google-api-core 2.7.1. google-cloud-memcache 1.0.0 has requirement
> google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-language 1.3.0 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-dlp 1.0.0 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-core 1.7.2 has requirement google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.21.0, but you have google-api-core 2.7.1.
> google-cloud-container 1.0.1 has requirement
> google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-cloud-bigtable 1.7.0 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core
> 2.7.1. google-api-python-client 1.12.8 has requirement google-api-core<2dev,>=1.21.0, but you have google-api-core 2.7.1.
> apache-beam 2.34.0 has requirement
> avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1, but you have avro-python3 1.10.0.
> The command '/bin/sh -c bash installer.sh $COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION
> fail' returned a non-zero code: 1 ERROR

before exporting my code to k8sPodOperator I want to understand what's the actual problem but I'm confused between those 2 errors.

PS: I've installed all those libraries on my local Airflow and they work perfectly fine together.

my composer version is : 1.17.7
my airflow version is: 2.1.4

any ideas what's the actual error preventing me from installing the library?

Comment: Which pypi packages are you trying to update? Have you tried to install its dependent packages?

Comment: confluent-kafka library. I havent tried to explicitly install them since it happens as part of the library installation. Looks like it conflict with google built in libraries

Comment: Can you try doing the library installation using the [latest version](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions) of composer and airflow?

Comment: Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: hey @PrajnaRaiT, your suggestion indeed solves the problem

Comment: Hi @gil, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the library using the [latest version](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions#images) of composer and airflow.